# Why is my script editor coming up with connection invalid after running it for a while?

Tags: applescript

This is the script I've found on the web I'm trying to just have the script drop items for me by pressing 1, but it works only for a little while before script comes up with an error "error "System Events got an error: Connection is invalid." number -609"

I use this script

```
delay 3  
tell application "RuneScape" to activate  
repeat  
    delay 5  
    set mydate to current date  
    repeat while ((current date) - mydate < 1)  
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke (key code 83)  
    end repeat  
end repeat
```

Comment: How many times are you expecting it to press the key? Once? Every 5 seconds? As fast as it can until tomorrow?

Comment: Well I really only want it to click a couple of times every 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

For a double-click every 5 seconds, until you quit the script, try just

```
delay 3  
tell application "RuneScape" to activate  
repeat  
    delay 5  
    tell application "System Events"  
        keystroke (key code 83)  
        keystroke (key code 83)  
    end tell  
end repeat
```

Comment: foe some reason when I try this it only wants to type 1 in the comments section it does not want to press 1 in my action bar. It seems to only work when I put the date section in there?